# Как при добавлении поста через wp_insert_post() присвоить ему тег таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function add_post_to_base(){
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
    $descr = $_POST['descr'];

    $post_data = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $descr,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );

    // Вставляем запись в базу данных
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    die('Post added');

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_post_to_base', 'add_post_to_base' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_post_to_base', 'add_post_to_base' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть параметр tax_input, но он раньше бажил, не знаю как сейчас. Поэтому лучший вариант использовать `wp_set_object_terms`:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $location, 'location' );
```

Comment: Да, все получилось, большое спасибо